# Fields of `NewView' not initialised

Tags: haskell, ihp

I'm trying to go through [the ihp blog tutorial](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/your-first-project.html#6-adding-comments), but I'm not sure how to resolve this error. I'm new to haskell. I've tried asking chat gpt, but no luck so far.

Do I need to initialize an empty comment when I create a post? I assume so because NewView is defined with that field.

### error

```
Web/Controller/Posts.hs:47:37
    * Fields of `NewView' not initialised:
        comment :: Comment
    * In the first argument of `render', namely `NewView {..}'
      In the expression: render NewView {..}
      In a case alternative: Left post -> render NewView {..}
   |
47 |                 Left post -> render NewView { .. }
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### source code

```
-- Web/Controller/Posts.hs
action CreatePostAction = do
    let post = newRecord @Post
    post
        |> buildPost
        |> ifValid \case
            Left post -> render NewView { .. }
            Right post -> do
                post <- post |> createRecord
                setSuccessMessage "Post created"
                redirectTo PostsAction
```

```
-- ./Web/View/Comments/New.hs
data NewView = NewView
    { comment :: Comment
    , post :: Post
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error happens as the view requires the `comment` variable to be passed from the controller action.

You've likely already set the `comment` variable inside your `NewPostAction`, something like this:

```hs
action NewPostAction = do
    let post = newRecord @Post
    let comment = newRecord @Comment
    render NewView { .. }
```

The `CreatePostAction` is also rendering the `NewView` when the validation of the newly submitted post has failed, to display the validation error messages. So you also need to set the `let comment = newRecord @Comment` inside the `Left` branch of the `CreatePostAction`:

```hs
-- Web/Controller/Posts.hs
action CreatePostAction = do
    let post = newRecord @Post
    post
        |> buildPost
        |> ifValid \case
            Left post -> do
                let comment = newRecord @Comment -- <--- THIS IS NEW
                render NewView { .. }
            Right post -> do
                post <- post |> createRecord
                setSuccessMessage "Post created"
                redirectTo PostsAction
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment field to a post's NewView. That was a mistake. Removing that field fixed things:

```
diff --git a/Web/View/Posts/New.hs b/Web/View/Posts/New.hs
index 79b073f..9cd06d0 100644
--- a/Web/View/Posts/New.hs
+++ b/Web/View/Posts/New.hs
@@ -3,8 +3,7 @@ import Web.View.Prelude
 import qualified Text.MMark as MMark
 
 data NewView = NewView
-    { comment :: Comment
-    , post :: Post
+    { post :: Post
     }
 
 instance View NewView where
```